# Remote debug java integration test on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jenkins, continuous-integration

guys

I have following problems:

I have a set of integration tests, locally they are working fine, but on the Jenkins they have failed.

Question: Can i debug it when jenkins run this integration test with maven **remotely**, like Remote Debug (like debug Tomcat or Weblogic) ?

Comment: The JVM used to launch your integration tests needs to have the debug flags set.  How do you launch them?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen jenkins run the build with some parameters, but  there is no debug paramater as  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n and etc. Jenkins runs maven wich runs tests, where the flag should be there?